# install private npm package in gitlab pipelines

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

If one needs to [install private repositories with npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/docker-and-private-modules) the environment variable `NPM_TOKEN` needs to be set.

```
NPM_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

My build stage in gitlab pipelines needs to install a private repository. Thus I put this `NPM_TOKEN` secret variable in my gitlab `pipeline` settings.

My current gitlab-ci configuration :

```
image: x/node

build_job: 
  script:
  - printenv NPM_TOKEN
  - npm i @x/test
```

The docker image is one that I made it just sets a `.npmrc` file:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY .npmrc .
```

where I have `.npmrc` in the same directory:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

I've tried the docker image by:

```
 run -it myimage bash
 export NPM_TOKEN=...
 npm i @x/test
```

That works, the private package is installed.

However on gitlab pipelines it does not find the package (404). When the job runs I can clearly see the `NPM_TOKEN` env variable being printed. So I don't know what's up.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I changed gitlab-ci to this:

```
image: dasnoo/node

build_job: 
  script:
  - printenv NPM_TOKEN
  - npm config set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken ${NPM_TOKEN}
  - npm i @dasnoo/testpriv
```

and it works. not sre why I had to do that though

Comment: Also worked for me when I had issues running the Dependency Scanning tool in GitLab. It's strange because having the ${NPM_TOKEN} in the environment worked before for builds and unit tests that we've run in the pipeline which also relied on the NPM_TOKEN.